# C: Why does integer act as long integer?

Tags: c, integer, range, variable-assignment, long-integer

From what I know an integer is in the range of 32,768 to 32,767.
A long integer is in the range of 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
I doubledchecked wikipedeia to make sure.

The problem now:

```
int a=2147483647;
printf("a: %d\n", a);
```

Why does this work? If I add 1 to 2147483647 then it prints garbage, something to be expected if the variable is a long integer. But why does it allow me to assign a long integer number to an integer in the first place?

Comment: Which wikipedia entry did you check? Integers on 32-bit machine should fall into the range -2b to +2b.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29 though I probably read it wrong. I had the idea that there is a standard on what size int, long int, float should be. But doesn't that mean that a program can behave very different on different processors? How would someone take care of this as a programmer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> From what I know an integer is in the range of 32,768 to 32,767.

This is incorrect.  The range of `int` is at least -32,767 to 32,767; it might have greater range and on most 32-bit and 64-bit platforms it does.

You can find out the range of the `int` type on your platform by checking the `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` macros defined in `<limits.h>`.

Comment: +1, although actually it has range at least +/-32767, not necessarily including -32768, to allow for the <s>stupid</s> other signed representations.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah; I was just looking that up since I figured it had to support signed magnitude and -32,768 to 32,767 would not.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

What you know is wrong.

Unlike some other languages like Java, the exact size of `int` and `long` in C is implementation defined (withing set limits).  Clearly, you are using a platform where `int` is 32 bits wide, but on other platforms it may be 16 bits, and on some platforms `int` is 64 bits wide.

Similarly, on some platforms, `long` is 32 bits wide; on others it is 64 bits wide.  It could be wider still if a platform chose to make it so.

Answer (score 4):

The real width of an `int` is generally implementation-dependent. You can use the `INT_MAX/INT_MIN` constants in the `limits.h` header to find out what the real range is.

On a x86 machine, an `int` is typically 4 bytes, so 2^31-1 is indeed the maximum value it can have.

Comment: "On an x86 machine `int` is ..." for values of x >= 3. For '286, '186 and '086, `int` was typically 2 bytes. But, unless the OP has a computer that is more than 20 years old, your statement is correct.

Answer (score 3):

sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)